# Facebook connect - Joms is not defined

Tags: facebook, joomla

Okay - My page www.praematures.dk - The facebook connect Works on the community tab, but not anywhere else. I get a JavaScript error saying -

> "ReferenceError: joms is not defined" - http://connect.facebook.net/da_DK/all.js

I've read that any other FB application can mess up the connecter variables, but even if I remove the Facebook like box on the front page, it still wont Work. Also - On the "artikel" tab and the "forum" tab - There is no other facebook scripts.

Comment: Joms is Jomsocial's ajax library, if you want to use it on pages where jomsocial is not present you have to manually add it or add to the page a jomsocial module which takes care of it.

Comment: I have it - As i use the module "Community - JomSocial Connect" that should take care of that - The module is loaded within the login module at the top of the screen

Comment: But even if i try to add the scripts in the login at the top, it doesnt Work.

Comment: This is really an issue for the jomsocial team; but if you want to fix it yourself, open the javascript console and look at the errors. Also compare the script declarations in the pages that work against the page that doesn't: this should give you a hint.